# nextInt() method in java

Tags: java

In java when I was working on Netbeans Ide I saw method of nextInt(int radix). I tried to implement this and passed an integer number, but that gave an exception of **InputMismatchException**. My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class HelloWorld{
public static void main(String args[]) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt(2);
System.out.println(n);
}
```

I want know that what is radix argument? Also,what is its use?

Comment: Do you had a look at java docs

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt(int)

Answer (score 6):

The radix is the base in which the number will be interpreted. You can use it to make the `nextInt` method interpret the number as non-decimal.

For example, the following expects a number in binary:

```
s.nextInt(2)
> 11111 //input
31 //result in decimal
```

And this expects a hex number:

```
s.nextInt(16)
> abc12 //input
703506 //result in decimal
```

You'll also be interested to see other methods using a radix, such as [Integer.toString(int, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int,%20int)), [Integer.parseInt(String, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)), which format/parse numbers in a specified radix (similar methods are provided by `Long`, `Short`, etc)